# fscanf read another format in same file.csv

Tags: c++, c, file

My data file:

```
name/month/date/year
1.Moore Harris,12/9/1995
2.Ragdoll Moore,11/5/2022
3.Sax,Smart,3/1/2033
4.Robert String,9/7/204
```

```
bool success = fscanf(fptr, "%[^,]", nameEmploy) == 1;
bool success = fscanf(fptr, ",%d", &month) == 1;
```

I only can read 1,2,4 and then the program skips No.3.
What should I use in this format to read it along with the other data?

Comment: Use `fgets` to read whole lines instead. Then use some way to parse the lines (`strtok` is a common and relatively simple way).

Comment: While the suggestion to use `fgets` is generally the right direction, you might also think about preventing such ill-formed content. If you use `','` to separate fields in your file, you might escape other commas within single fields. Or enclose such entries in quotes,e tc.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will change to **fgets** instead of fscanf but it is possible to do with fscanf or not?

Comment: No,I think it will not be possible to properly scan names with `,` in it with a single format string.

Comment: @SupportUkraine Given the statement that only lines 1,2 and 4 can be read properly, I think this is not a copy&paste mistake but intentional. Also the title mentioned "another format". Therefore I assume the main issue is mixing delimiter into field content.

Comment: You need a technology that supports backtracking, since in your example data any particular comma can be a field separator or text content, and it's impossible to know which one until the rest of the line is read.  Regular expressions are frequently chosen when backtracking is required... C++ recently added regex to the standard library, and PCRE is a regex library that's been available for use in C and C++ for much longer.

Comment: Thank you everyone, Now I got it by using the first recommend by @Someprogrammerdude dude to use `fgets` and `strtok` to parse the line!

Comment: @PorrutaiRidtinontachai Parsing with `strspn()/strcspn()` instead of `strtok()` avoids changing the `strtok()` hidden global variable and works with `const` strings.

Comment: I submit that your CSV is _malformed_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To parse the CSV file, it is recommended to read one line at a time with `fgets()` and use `sscanf()` to parse all fields in one call:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct data {
    char name[32];
    int month, day, year;
};

int parse_csv(FILE *fp) {
    char buf[256];
    char c[2];
    struct data entry;
    int count = 0;

    while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, fp)) {
        if (sscanf(buf, "%31[^,],%d/%d/%d%1[\n]",
                   entry.name, &entry.month, &entry.day, &entry.year, c) == 5) {
            add_entry(&entry);
            count++;
        } else {
            printf("invalid line: %.*s\n", (int)strcspn(buf, "\n"), buf);
        }
    }
    return count; 
}
```

Note however these shortcomings:

- lines longer than 254 bytes will cause errors
- fields cannot be quoted
- the `name` field cannot contain `,`
- empty fields cannot be parsed by `sscanf`

Comment: This won't help read the line that contains a comma inside the first column.

Comment: @BenVoigt: indeed this is a simplistic parser. Answer amended with caveats